# Typesetting on block matrix is ugly

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I have a large `n` x `n` matrix I'm trying to typeset.  My current code is as follows:

```
$\left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \\
\hline
0  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\Huge{$A$}}} \\
\vdots & & &\\
0 & & & 
\end{array}\right)$
```

The output is currently terrible in a number of ways. First, the large block `A` matrix (which is supposed to be an `(n-1)` x `(n-1)` submatrix) is not centered properly. Second, the vertical dots on the left hand side are not properly vertically centered. Third, it is just visually unappealing in a way that I can't quite put my finger on.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to typeset this in a better manner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another option would be to use a two-column `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
  1 & c_2 \cdots c_n \\ \hline
  0 & \raisebox{-15pt}{{\huge\mbox{{$A$}}}} \\[-4ex]
  \vdots & \\[-0.5ex]
  0 &
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Although there are some personal preferences built into this question (and therefore some subjectivity), I have some suggestions.

You can play around with the vertical alignment using the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) command `\raisebox{<height>}{<stuff>}`:

```
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
...
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \\ \hline
    0  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\raisebox{-7mm}{\scalebox{2}{$[A]$}}}} \\
    \raisebox{2pt}{\vdots} & & &\\
    0 & & & 
  \end{array}\right)
\]
```

[image]

I've also added some brackets around the inner matrix `A` to accentuate the fact that it could be considered a matrix. The size of the inner/sub-matrix has also been set using `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` from the `graphicx` package, since `\Huge` is a textmode font command. Using colour for certain parts of the matrix may also highlight the scope of the matrix. In the example below, cells within the array were coloured using 10% black (via `black!10`):

```
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{colortbl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
...
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \\ \hline
    0  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{black!10}} \\
    \raisebox{2pt}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{black!10}\scalebox{2}{$[A]$}} \\
    0 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{black!10}}
  \end{array}\right)
\]
```

[image]

At lower resolution the coloured matrix may should some problems. However, this should only be visible in your viewer and not the actual print.

Alignment of the brackets around the matrix can also be adjusted, but I'm not sure whether this is part of the "can't quite put my finger on [it]" part.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it is not the best solution. However, you might also try to put array inside another array. In your case it is

```
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
  1 & \begin{array}{ccc} c_2 & \cdots & c_n \end{array} \\ \hline
\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{array}  & {\Huge{A}}
\end{array}
\right)
\]
```

The spacing is not optimal in this case, however.

Answer (score 0):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots/shorten=6pt}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[hvlines,margin]
1 & c_2 & \Cdots & c_n \\
0 & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{A} \\
\Vdots \\
0 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]